# Give Azure Table Storage access to Azure AD B2C users

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-table-storage, azure-keyvault

I would like to use Azure Table Storage (not Cosmos DB - I know Cosmos DB supports Azure AD but is too expensive for my usecase) in an Angular App which already authenticates users via the npm package @azure/msal-angular. I only require an "Editor" group and editors should be allowed to edit data in Table Storage while everyone else is allowed to read.

What I would like to achieve is the ability to assign the "Editor" role in Azure AD B2C and then I want to securely access Table Storage from Angular with write access.

I read that this is somehow doable with Azure Key Vault as an intermediary, but I cannot figure out how that works. I could use an Azure Function in the middle and access Key Vault and build the Table Storage url with an SAS token inside the function - but I would like to get this to work without the Function in the middle - is that at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure AD B2C users can only gain access to *your* applications. Azure AD B2C users cannot gain access to Azure/O365 services/APIs - you have to use Azure AD.

Comment: My bad. I guess when B2C users cannot be used to authorize access to Azure resources, it will still be possible to determine inside an Azure Function that a logged in B2C user called the Function, right? I could then tunnel only the calls that require write access through the Azure Function to Azure Table Storage and make sure those B2C users have the "Editor" role.

Comment: Yes you can do that. B2C user calls your azure function, you maintain an RBAC table and check based on the incoming token claims whether the user has the right access. You can log/data mine here. Your azure function can use Azure AD client credentials to talk to other Azure Services.